# Why was second question about Offences Against the Person Act 1861 closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[Offences Against the Person Act 1861 — How's s 47 "in at least one respect, the narrowest offence of" ss 18, 20, 47?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/45044/2807) is about s 47. Why was it closed as duplicating [Offences Against the Person Act 1861 — How is Section 18 , in at least one respect broader than Section 20?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/45047/2807) about s 18? ss 18 and 47 aren't same thing!!!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it was closed because the answer in the latter responds to both questions.

Answer (score 1):

I closed them because the questions you asked are:

> I don't ken the emboldening. Here's the OATPA 1861.
>
> 1. How's s.47 "in at least one respect, the narrowest offence of" ss. 18, 20, 47?
> 2. Are there more respects than just "one respect"? How many exactly? What are they?

and

> I don't understand the bold text in the OATPA 1861.
>
> 1. How is s. 18 "in at least one respect, broader than section 20"?
> 2. Are there more respects than just "one respect"? How many exactly? What are they?

These look like mirror images to me.

Comment: Pls reread both questions 1. They're unmistakably NOT identical.